# Does Sentry have an API?

Tags: api, sentry

Is there an API I could use to get data, such as the number of events over the past day ?
I'd like to incorporate this data into my own dashboard.

I read in the documentation that you can write some plugins (ie: to create  webhooks) but it doesn't fit with what I need.

Answer (score 2):

There is this Web API of sentry. You can find the documentation [here](https://app.getsentry.com/docs/api/#schema).
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's an API but you could use the webhooks, just go to your project page -> Settings -> Manage Integrations, it's the last one on the list

Hope this helps

Comment: No because it would be only uselful I wanted to be notified each time an event is received.

Comment: @Nicolas You could always just a) check if it's the kind of event you want; b) overwrite a single stored JSON object/maintain a cached list and poll that